# Shortcut for website using non-default browser

Tags: group-policy, shortcut

I am working on a GPO to push a desktop shortcut to a website using IE (which is not the default browser) out to my Windows 7 Pro machines. All machines are x64. Not sure why this isn't working:

- Action: Update (tried Create too, but that didn't help)
- Name: BackOffice
- Target Type: File System
- Object Location: Desktop
- Target path: "%programfiles(x86)%\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" https:\xxxx (with the real address of course)
- Arguments: (tried putting the URL here instead of Target path, but that didn't help)
- Start in: %programfiles(x86)%\internet explorer\ (tried blank too, but that didn't work)
- Shortcut key: none
- Run: Normal window
- Comment:
- Icon file path: UNC to an icon file here (checked that the user can pull it up via UNC)
- Icon index: 0

But we keep getting an event log: 4098 - The user 'Back Office' preference item in the policy POLICYName did not apply because it failed with error code XXXX. The system cannot find the file specified. This error was suppressed.

I can copy the target path out of the policy and paste it into Run on the target workstation and it works perfectly.

Comment: If chrome happens to be the default browser you may want to look at the legacy browser extension for chrome.  It is configured via gpo to automatically switch to ie for specified sites.

Comment: Do you know of a specific extension that I can configure that way via GPO? I've got IETab installed on all the computers, and I can set it to auto-open for certain sites, but I don't know of a way to control it via GPO.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but have you tried removing the URL bit, and just focused on getting a working shortcut that starts IE?  If you can't get a working shortcut just for IE, that might reveal something useful.  If you can, then it should be just adding the URL as an argument.

Comment: I actually tried that, and got the same error.

Comment: @mscf exact name is "legacy browser support extension" https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3019558?hl=en read the guide it will walk you through setting it up to autoinstall on domain pcs and configure via gpo.

Comment: @mscf linked to from that page is a complete guide for enterprise deployment of chrome and the legacy browser support extension.  We use it at my work because some webapps require ie and others require NOT ie.  It works quite well no need to set anything from each workstation all controlled by gpo.

Comment: What happens if you don't set the Object location to the Desktop and instead you give the full path to something like c:\users\public\desktop\backoffice.lnk or something?  BTW are you applying at the computer wide, or user level?

Comment: @grant - that looks interesting. giving it a try now.

Comment: @Zoredache - I'll give that a try when I'm back in the office. I'm applying the policy at the user level.

Comment: @grant - any pointers on the legacy browser settings? I've got "mscf-pos01" set in the Host to open in Alternative Browser, and the address I'm trying to go to is https ://mscf-pos01/somestuffhere. I also tried "https://mscf-pos01". Doesn't open up in IE. I did verify the extension is installed, as well as the IE Support MSI.

Comment: @mscf try adding it to the list both with and without the https:// part...I forget which way you need to specify it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following below. I've just tested it and works fine.

- **Action:** Create
- **Name:** BackOffice
- **Target Type:** File System Object
- **Location:** Desktop
- **Target Path:** %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
- **Arguements:** http://www.google.com
- **Start In:**    (BLANK)
- **Shortcut Key:** None
- **Run:** Normal Window
- **Comment:** N/A
- **Icon file path:**
- **Icon Index:**

I have just tried various different ways of UNC path for the icon file but none of them appear to work including trying \domain.local\sysvol path. I created a GPO to copy the icon from a shared location to a location on the local machine then pointed the Shortcut Group Policy to the Icon on the local machine and it works fine!

Comment: This does work. Thank you. I wonder why the icon path doesn't want to work. I did notice that all the default options have a .dll in the icon path, and then an Icon Index. Maybe you can't point directly at a .ico file?

Comment: I managed to point directly to an .ico file but only if it was located on the local computer. So I created a GPO to copy the .ico file from a shared location to local computer then pointed the Shortcut Icon file path to the path on the local computer! Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Strange thing is, I can use the same icon file on a URL shortcut and it works.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the Group Policy creation of shortcut and handling UNC paths.

Answer (score 0):

For win 8 users make sure you enable this in GP:

Computer Config --> Admin Templates --> Windows Components --> File Explorer --> "Allow the use of remote paths in file shortcut icons"